# android: how to pinch zoom without triggering a click (ACTION_DOWN)

Tags: android, touch, zooming, usability

Currently I have a zoom implemented for my drawing application which works quite well. Just some lines so you know what I'm talking about:

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
                WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);

                // Handle touch events here...
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawSomethingHere();
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    startZoomingModeHere();
...
```

So what I want is: draw with one finger, zoom with both fingers.
Problem is: there is always a ACTION_DOWN event triggered BEFORE the second finger hits the surface. So everytime I want to zoom, my app draws a point before the zoom mode is started.

Does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows:

1. Draw on ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE instead of ACTION_DOWN
2. On ACTION_MOVE don't draw immediately, put the points in a buffer instead (this will make sure that you don't interpret accidental single touch events before the multitouch event happens)
3. as soon as the buffer has 3 points, start the drawing mode
4. as soon as an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN event occurs (multitouch happened), clear the buffer and start zooming mode

This is the best I could do. The result is pretty convincing...

Comment: I am facing the same problem..could you further elaborate on the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait some milliseconds before starting draw, because it's impossible to put exactly two fingers at same millisecond.

You could have a boolean var to wait.

boolean boolean_pointer_down = false;

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             // Start a thread to call drawSomethingHere in 300 - 700 milliseconds
             // if action_pointer_down haven’t been called.
             new  ThreadDraw().start();
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
               boolean_pointer_down=true;
                startZoomingModeHere();
....

//Method run in the thread
public void run(){
   wait(300); //if the user didn't put more fingers in 300 ms he's not going to zoom
    if (!boolean_pointer_down){
    drawSomethingHere();
    boolean_pointer_down = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thats an idea. but if the user wants to draw, he/she has to be able to draw without waiting. With your code, the user would realize some latency when drawing :/